# passing selectBox value to applied template xslt

Tags: php, ajax, xslt, symphony-cms

Hello all I have a following snipped of an xslt template:

```
<select name="weightoption" id="weightoption">

                        <xsl:for-each select="product-waights/entry">
                            <option>
                                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="price"/>

                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="weight"/>


                            </option>

                        </xsl:for-each>


                    </select>
                    <xsl:variable name="item" select="menu-dish/entry/price" />


                    <xsl:apply-templates select="menu-dish"   mode="menu_dish_information" >
                        <xsl:with-param name="price" select="$item"/>

                    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

There I have a selectBoks "weightoption" and a variable item that I want to make equal to selectBox'es value. And if user change the selecton to update the value and pass it as a parameter to a template. I know how to do it with html/ajax, but not sure how to do it using xslt. Please advise me on this...
Also, I am adding my xml file if it will help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <params>
        <today>2021-09-17</today>
        <current-time>16:38</current-time>
        <this-year>2021</this-year>
        <this-month>09</this-month>
        <this-day>17</this-day>
        <timezone>+03:00</timezone>
        <website-name>Coffeeport</website-name>
        <page-title>Блюдо</page-title>
        <root>https://www.coffeeport.ru</root>
        <workspace>https://www.coffeeport.ru/workspace</workspace>
        <workspace-path>/workspace</workspace-path>
        <http-host>www.coffeeport.ru</http-host>
        <root-page>menu</root-page>
        <current-page>dish</current-page>
        <current-page-id>22</current-page-id>
        <current-path>/menu/food/torty-na-zakaz/tort1</current-path>
        <parent-path>/menu/categories/dishes</parent-path>
        <current-query-string><![CDATA[debug=xml]]></current-query-string>
        <current-url>https://www.coffeeport.ru/menu/food/torty-na-zakaz/tort1</current-url>
        <upload-limit>134217728</upload-limit>
        <symphony-version>2.7.7</symphony-version>
        <type-slug>food</type-slug>
        <category-slug>torty-na-zakaz</category-slug>
        <dish-slug>tort1</dish-slug>
        <cookie-xsrf-token>4he1qkd5kDX9RiQoOr1hF3PjJatxjV</cookie-xsrf-token>
        <cookie-username>p.ivanov</cookie-username>
        <cookie-pass>PBKDF2v1|10000|b3fbb565869af1c0c2f8|EKIe+sVXNrj3nLyLgpP5/2ipUwp5Bqvsdhm453yWpr7+MlPyPYlULA==</cookie-pass>
        <page-types />
        <page-events>
            <item handle="feedback">feedback</item>
            <item handle="canofspam">canofspam</item>
            <item handle="subscribe">subscribe</item>
        </page-events>
        <recaptcha-sitekey>6LclP8UUAAAAAJPu6n28M7eN8jXbTfy-i814Sorr</recaptcha-sitekey>
        <canofspam>d922f7c7543f732ecdc9756758aa2c838b155973</canofspam>
        <ds-menu-category-id-by-slug.system-id>
            <item handle="84653">84653</item>
        </ds-menu-category-id-by-slug.system-id>
        <ds-menu-category-id-by-slug>
            <item handle="84653">84653</item>
        </ds-menu-category-id-by-slug>
        <ds-menu-type-id-by-slug.system-id>
            <item handle="72">72</item>
        </ds-menu-type-id-by-slug.system-id>
        <ds-menu-type-id-by-slug>
            <item handle="72">72</item>
        </ds-menu-type-id-by-slug>
        <ds-product-waights.weight>
            <item handle="2-kg">2 кг</item>
            <item handle="1-kg">1 кг</item>
        </ds-product-waights.weight>
        <ds-product-waights.price>
            <item handle="800">800</item>
            <item handle="500">500</item>
        </ds-product-waights.price>
        <ds-product-waights.product>
            <item handle="84680">84680</item>
            <item handle="84680">84680</item>
        </ds-product-waights.product>
        <ds-menu-dish.system-id>
            <item handle="84680">84680</item>
        </ds-menu-dish.system-id>
        <ds-menu-dish.section>
            <item handle="84653">84653</item>
        </ds-menu-dish.section>
        <ds-menu-dish.group />
    </params>
    <events>
        <member-login-info logged-in="no" />
    </events>
    <contacts>
        <section id="9" handle="contacts">Контакты</section>
        <entry id="16">
            <phone handle="8-800-777-02-18">8 800 777-02-18</phone>
            <working-hours handle="s-9-00-do-20-00">с 9:00 до 20:00</working-hours>
            <email handle="help-coffeeportru">help@coffeeport.ru</email>
            <address handle="125047-g-moskva-ul-1-aya-brestskaya-d-62-pom-4">125047, г. Москва, ул. 1-ая Брестская, д. 62, пом. 4</address>
            <legal mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Юридический адрес :&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
125047, г. Москва, ул. 1-ая Брестская, д. 62, пом. 4&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;ОГРН :&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
1197746491183&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;ИНН/КПП :&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
9710077501/771001001&lt;/p&gt;
</legal>
            <text mode="formatted">&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;Вам есть, что сказать или предложить? &lt;br /&gt;
Мы рады Вас услышать! &lt;br /&gt;
Свяжитесь с нами любым удобным для Вас способом:&lt;/p&gt;
</text>
        </entry>
    </contacts>
    <menu-category-id-by-slug>
        <section id="2" handle="menu-categories">Категории меню</section>
        <entry id="84653">
            <name handle="torty-na-zakaz-v-razrabotke">Торты на заказ (В разработке)</name>
            <slug>torty-na-zakaz</slug>
            <image>
                <item>
                    <file size="701 KB" path="/public/images/sections" type="image/jpeg" extension="jpg">
                        <filename>desert_glavnaya.jpg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2020-12-10T20:32:12+03:00" width="3500" height="2333" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </image>
            <default-image>
                <item>
                    <file size="15 KB" path="/public/images/menu/categories" type="image/jpeg" extension="jpeg">
                        <filename>bez-nazvaniya-1-.jpeg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2020-12-10T20:32:17+03:00" width="263" height="191" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </default-image>
        </entry>
    </menu-category-id-by-slug>
    <menu-type-id-by-slug>
        <section id="22" handle="menu-types">Типы меню</section>
        <entry id="72">
            <name handle="eda">Еда</name>
            <slug>food</slug>
            <description mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;Еда в КОФЕПОРТ — это оригинальные и традиционные рецепты, разнообразная выпечка и вкусности. Мы готовим для вас только из свежих и качественных ингредиентов. Наша еда - это всегда отличное дополнение к горячим и холодным напиткам, на любой вкус и в любое время дня.&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
            <text mode="formatted">&lt;h2&gt;Приятного аппетита!&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Мы рады предложить нашим гостям десерты собственного производства, свежие салаты, горячий суп, вкусные сэндвичи и роллы. Вы можете позавтракать или пообедать прямо в кофейне или взять еду с собой в офис или на прогулку. Мы готовим только из натуральных ингредиентов, не добавляя компонентов, увеличивающих срок годности наших вкусностей и выпечки. Поэтому каждое утро в КОФЕПОРТ вы найдете только самую качественную и свежую продукцию, произведенную в этот же день.&lt;/p&gt;
</text>
        </entry>
    </menu-type-id-by-slug>
    <presentation-file>
        <section id="19" handle="presentation">Презентация</section>
        <entry id="36">
            <file>
                <item>
                    <file size="6.84 MB" path="/public/files/presentation" type="application/pdf" extension="pdf">
                        <filename>coffeeport_prezentatsiya_04.01.2021.pdf</filename>
                        <meta creation="2021-01-11T09:41:14+03:00" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </file>
        </entry>
    </presentation-file>
    <menu-categories-all>
        <section id="2" handle="menu-categories">Категории меню</section>
        <type link-id="72" link-handle="eda" value="Еда">
            <entry id="2">
                <name handle="vkusnosti">Вкусности</name>
                <slug>bakery</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="4">
                <name handle="deserty">Десерты</name>
                <slug>deserts</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="5">
                <name handle="zavtraki">Завтраки</name>
                <slug>breakfasts</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="140">
                <name handle="rolly">Роллы</name>
                <slug>rolly</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="141">
                <name handle="cupy">Cупы</name>
                <slug>supy</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="153">
                <name handle="salaty">Салаты</name>
                <slug>salaty</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="154">
                <name handle="sendvichi">Сэндвичи </name>
                <slug>sendvichi</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="20930">
                <name handle="pirogi-na-zakaz">Пироги на заказ</name>
                <slug>pirogi-na-zakaz</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="84653">
                <name handle="torty-na-zakaz-v-razrabotke">Торты на заказ (В разработке)</name>
                <slug>torty-na-zakaz</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="72" handle="eda" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Еда</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
        </type>
        <type link-id="387" link-handle="dobavki" value="Добавки">
            <entry id="147">
                <name handle="siropy">Сиропы</name>
                <slug>dobavki-k-goryachim-napitkam-i-kofe</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="387" handle="dobavki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Добавки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="391">
                <name handle="dobavki">Добавки</name>
                <slug>dobavki</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="387" handle="dobavki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Добавки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="454">
                <name handle="spetsii">Специи</name>
                <slug>spetsii</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="387" handle="dobavki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Добавки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
        </type>
        <type link-id="390" link-handle="napitki" value="Напитки">
            <entry id="148">
                <name handle="goryachie-napitki">Горячие напитки </name>
                <slug>goryachie-napitki</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="390" handle="napitki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Напитки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="150">
                <name handle="holodnye-napitki">Холодные напитки </name>
                <slug>holodnye-napitki</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="390" handle="napitki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Напитки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="151">
                <name handle="svezhevyzhatye-soki">Свежевыжатые соки</name>
                <slug>svezhevyzhatye-soki-na-100-ml</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="390" handle="napitki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Напитки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
            <entry id="397">
                <name handle="kofejnye-napitki">Кофейные напитки</name>
                <slug>kofejnye-napitki</slug>
                <type>
                    <item id="390" handle="napitki" section-handle="menu-types" section-name="Типы меню">Напитки</item>
                </type>
            </entry>
        </type>
    </menu-categories-all>
    <map-cities>
        <section id="20" handle="cities">Города</section>
        <entry id="37">
            <name handle="moskva">Москва</name>
            <slug>moscow</slug>
        </entry>
    </map-cities>
    <menu-types>
        <section id="22" handle="menu-types">Типы меню</section>
        <entry id="72">
            <name handle="eda">Еда</name>
            <slug>food</slug>
            <image>
                <item>
                    <file size="1.39 MB" path="/public/images/menu/categories" type="image/jpeg" extension="jpg">
                        <filename>zastavka-eda.jpg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2019-09-30T20:11:00+03:00" width="3000" height="2002" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </image>
            <description mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;Еда в КОФЕПОРТ — это оригинальные и традиционные рецепты, разнообразная выпечка и вкусности. Мы готовим для вас только из свежих и качественных ингредиентов. Наша еда - это всегда отличное дополнение к горячим и холодным напиткам, на любой вкус и в любое время дня.&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
        </entry>
        <entry id="390">
            <name handle="napitki">Напитки</name>
            <slug>drinks</slug>
            <image>
                <item>
                    <file size="107 KB" path="/public/images/menu/categories" type="image/jpeg" extension="jpg">
                        <filename>zastavka-na-razdel-napitki.jpg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2019-11-06T10:34:06+03:00" width="1404" height="937" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </image>
            <description mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;Хороший кофе — наша работа. Напитки от КОФЕПОРТ- это прекрасный способ взбодриться перед началом рабочего дня и хороший повод сделать паузу в напряженном рабочем графике. Наслаждайтесь каждый день!&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
        </entry>
        <entry id="387">
            <name handle="dobavki">Добавки</name>
            <slug>syrups</slug>
            <image>
                <item>
                    <file size="944 KB" path="/public/images/menu/categories" type="image/png" extension="png">
                        <filename>dobavki_na_glavnuyu.png</filename>
                        <meta creation="2018-12-24T17:57:04+03:00" width="1248" height="590" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </image>
            <description mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;У нас вы всегда можете попробовать что-то новое или придать знакомому напитку необычный вкус. Попросите нашего сотрудника добавить в кофе один из наших фирменных сиропов и не забудьте про корицу и другие пряности. Экспериментируйте: добавок у нас очень много!&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
        </entry>
    </menu-types>
    <map-city-first>
        <section id="20" handle="cities">Города</section>
        <entry id="37">
            <slug>moscow</slug>
        </entry>
    </map-city-first>
    <cart id="82222" price="0" discount="0" calories="0" calories-calc="0">
        <section id="3" handle="dishes">Блюда</section>
        <error>No records found.</error>
        <cards quantity="0"></cards>
    </cart>
    <delivery-index>
        <section id="40" handle="delivery">Доставка</section>
        <entry id="1766">
            <title handle="dostavka">Доставка</title>
            <slug>delivery</slug>
        </entry>
    </delivery-index>
    <highlight>
        <section id="47" handle="highlight">Уведомление</section>
        <entry id="32297">
            <text mode="formatted">
&lt;p&gt;На сайте работает доставка, и появилась возможность забронировать вкусности в любимой кофейне. Для этого сделайте заказ в &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.coffeeport.ru/menu/&quot;&gt;меню&lt;/a&gt;. Как это &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.coffeeport.ru/info/delivery/&quot;&gt;работает&lt;/a&gt;?&lt;/p&gt;
</text>
            <order-notice handle="besplatnyj-samovyvoz-iz-lyuboj-nashej-kofejni-soglasno-grafiku-raboty">Бесплатный самовывоз из любой нашей кофейни согласно графику работы.</order-notice>
        </entry>
    </highlight>
    <product-waights>
        <section id="48" handle="waights">веса продуктов</section>
        <entry id="85990">
            <weight handle="2-kg">2 кг</weight>
            <price handle="800">800</price>
            <product entries="84680" sections="3" x-data-source-mode="dishes.name, dishes.slug" x-field-included-elements="dishes.name, dishes.slug">
                <item id="84680" level="1" max-level="-1" section-id="3" section="dishes" matched-element="slug">
                    <name handle="tort-1">Торт 1</name>
                    <slug>tort1</slug>
                </item>
            </product>
        </entry>
        <entry id="84286">
            <weight handle="1-kg">1 кг</weight>
            <price handle="500">500</price>
            <product entries="84680" sections="3" x-data-source-mode="dishes.name, dishes.slug" x-field-included-elements="dishes.name, dishes.slug">
                <item id="84680" level="1" max-level="-1" section-id="3" section="dishes" matched-element="slug">
                    <name handle="tort-1">Торт 1</name>
                    <slug>tort1</slug>
                </item>
            </product>
        </entry>
    </product-waights>
    <menu-dish>
        <section id="3" handle="dishes">Блюда</section>
        <entry id="84680">
            <name handle="tort-1">Торт 1</name>
            <weight handle="1">1</weight>
            <price handle="500">500</price>
            <short-description mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;Тестовый продукт не заказывать&lt;/p&gt;
</short-description>
            <description mode="formatted">&lt;p&gt;Тестовый продукт не заказывать&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
            <images>
                <item>
                    <file size="994 KB" path="/public/images/dishes" type="image/jpeg" extension="jpg">
                        <filename>101kruassan-mindalnyi-.jpg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2020-12-10T20:32:05+03:00" width="3500" height="1972" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </images>
            <forbidden>No</forbidden>
            <coffeehouse>No</coffeehouse>
            <mini>No</mini>
            <consist><![CDATA[Не известно]]></consist>
            <calories>100</calories>
            <energy-value>50</energy-value>
            <protein>80</protein>
            <fat>90</fat>
            <carbohydrates>50</carbohydrates>
        </entry>
    </menu-dish>
    <menu-dish-same-category>
        <section id="3" handle="dishes">Блюда</section>
        <entry id="84680">
            <name handle="tort-1">Торт 1</name>
            <slug>tort1</slug>
            <weight handle="1">1</weight>
            <price handle="500">500</price>
            <images>
                <item>
                    <file size="994 KB" path="/public/images/dishes" type="image/jpeg" extension="jpg">
                        <filename>101kruassan-mindalnyi-.jpg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2020-12-10T20:32:05+03:00" width="3500" height="1972" />
                    </file>
                </item>
            </images>
            <forbidden>No</forbidden>
            <coffeehouse>No</coffeehouse>
            <mini>No</mini>
        </entry>
    </menu-dish-same-category>
    <menu-dishes-by-group>
        <section id="3" handle="dishes">Блюда</section>
        <error required-param="$ds-menu-dish.group">Data source not executed, required parameter is missing.</error>
    </menu-dishes-by-group>
</data>
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to familiarise yourself with Symphony CMS [events](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/events/) and/or [URL parameters](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/).

[This tutorial](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/tutorials/view/say-hello-to-symphony/) may be helpful.